# idl2java does not work with 64bit JVM? Error loading jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

Tags: java, jvm, corba, idl

**vbroker52\bin\idl2java.exe -verbose -VBJdebug -VBJjavavm**

```
D:\tools\java\jdk1.6.0_37_32\jre\bin\java.exe  
JVM:  
    Loaded JVM dll D:\tools\java\jdk1.6.0_37_32\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll  
JavaVMInitArgs:  
...
```

**vbroker52\bin\idl2java.exe -verbose -VBJdebug -VBJjavavm**

```
D:\tools\java\jdk1.6.0_37_64\jre\bin\java.exe  
Error loading: D:\tools\java\jdk1.6.0_37_64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll  
Unable to load any JVM, exiting!!!
```

I tried several versions of JVM - the problem exists only if 64bit JVM is used.
Is it known bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old visibroker idl compiler cannot deal with a 64Bit Java runtime. This won't work. But you can try to create the java code (with idl2java) with a 32Bit JVM and compile it with a 64Bit JDK.